# MySQL how to merge 3 rows and count the results?

Tags: mysql

I am currently writing a small script, and I'm stuck since this morning.

Here are my fields :

`id | player1 | player2 | player3`

Sample rows : 


`1 | toto | -    | -

2 | tata | toto | -

3 | titi | tutu | -

4 | tata | titi | toto`

I'd like to be able to merge the rows player1, player2, player3 and count the number of entries, to get a top that would be like this, according to the example rows I gave : 
toto 3
tata 2
tutu 2
titi 1

I'm usually writing basic queries, so for that one, I'm really stuck, trying stuff for hours now, and can't get what I want.. Any idea PLEASE ?

Comment: Do you have some table which lists all the players?

Comment: Did you mean `I'd like to be able to merge the columns player1...`?

Comment: @ penartur : no, no list, everything is in the table. 
@ Mosty Mostacho : what I need is to get a list of all the players, whether there are in the row player1, player2 or player3, and count the number of times they are listed, to have a list of the players that have the biggest number of records.

Answer (score 2):

It reads as though you are starting out on something, and already your database design is quite un-normalised which can lead to performance issues down the line.  In order to reduce this I would suggest considering a restructuring before you get much further.  Player 1, player 2, and player 3 are all players and so able to be normalised.  Each row of your existing table can be considered to be a `game` or similar and so can be normalised.  You are then just presented with the task of linking players to games.  That way you are not storing the same players details multiple times, and all queries against the tables will end up being faster in the long run, even if the initial insert is a bit more complex.

```
players (
    id INT UNSIGNED PK AI,
    name VARCHAR
    .... other player data ....
)

// Assumed a name here
games (
    id INT UNSIGNED PK AI
    .... game data ....
)

// Note the 2-field primary key here.  Prevents 1 player being in the same game twice.
playersInGames (
    game_id INT UNSIGNED PK,
    player_id INT UNSIGNED PK,
    playerNumber TINYINT UNSIGNED  // You don't even need this, if you don't care about player number assigments just don't include this column
)
```

Example data

```
// players
id      name
1       toto
2       tata
3       titi
4       tutu

// games
id
1
2
3
4

// playersInGames
game_id     player_id       playerNumber
1           1               1
2           2               1
2           1               2
3           3               1
3           4               2
4           2               1
4           3               2
4           1               3
```

This would in turn let you do simple queries such as

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    COUNT(DISTINCT pig.game_id) AS gamesPlayerIsIn
FROM players AS p
LEFT JOIN playersInGames AS pig
ON pig.player_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
```

**edit** if you really don't want to change the table schema, the following will suffice but will make whoever maintains your code cry.  It will count each player up to once per table row.

```
SELECT
    players.playerName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT players.id) AS numberOfRows
FROM (
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT id, player1 AS playerName FROM tableName
    ) UNION DISTINCT (
        SELECT DISTINCT id, player2 AS playerName FROM tableName
    ) UNION DISTINCT (
        SELECT DISTINCT id, player3 AS playerName FROM tableName
    )
) AS players
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from ((select id,player1 as players from tablename) union (select id,player2 as players from tablename) union (select id,player3 as players from tablename)) as dummytable group by players
```

I haven't tested but look at the logic :)